# Substitution/Replacement problem with a data file Perl, Sublime

Tags: perl

My file is x in the format \D{5}\d\d/ D{5}\d or |D{5}dd
example:

```
aahed9aalii5aargh9abaca9abaci9aback13
```

The /d may be 1 or 2 digits no spaces or breaks in the entire document.

The goal is to create a .csv file dividing the \D{5} from \d{1} or \d{2}
Tried sublime text,perl,textedit or pages

In Sublime I understand how to find the (\D{5} group) but not how to replace that with (\D{5}),)

I found the s(dog/cat)substitution example but could not get that to translate in perl or sublime.

Found the perl command line idea
(`perl -pi.bak -e 's\/D{5}/D{5}\,/g' $filename`) may not be exact
But could not decipher all the errors

The reason I chose regex for this is the only commonality to each value is the length of the word is the same throughout the document. There are no tabs, no parens, no spaces, no fixed length fields nothing to get my hooks in.
The question:
How do I retain the original values in the replace/substitution function?

I realize what this board has to deal with in regard to duplicate
questions. Do you realize on my side how difficult it is to search through all the previous questions when I am not sure what I am looking for?

I am not looking for someone to give me a fish, looking for someone to teach me how to fish.

If REGEX is not the answer maybe I am missing something any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `\D{5}\d\d` means match a non-numeric character 5 times, followed by 2 numericals. `|D{5}dd` means either match the empty string OR a literal D 5 times, followed by literal dd. (`|` is an alternator). `/ D{5}\d` means match a slash (assuming delimiter is changed), followed by a space and a literal D 5 times and one numerical. You should be more precise about how you write backslash `\ `.

Answer (score 2):

The `$1`, `$2`, etc variables may be used to refer back to "captures" (parenthesized parts) within the most recent regexp.

```
echo aahed9aalii5aargh9abaca9abaci9aback13 | perl -pe 's/(\D{5})(\d*)/$1=$2,/g'
```

Outputs:

```
aahed=9,aalii=5,aargh=9,abaca=9,abaci=9,aback=13,
```